# How to solve "System limit for number of file watchers reached" issue when using GitLab CI?

Tags: reactjs, docker, react-native, gitlab-ci-runner, watchman

I have problem a with build React-Native app using Gitlab CI.
My build always fails with error:

```
    ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch ~
```

**What i tried:**

- Increase 'fs.inotify.max_user_watches' value with command  ...

  ```
   echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
  ```

... inside gitlab-ci.yml file. This solution works on my private gitlab.com account but with the self-hosted by company unfortunately got error:

```
     sysctl: permission denied on key 'fs.inotify.max_user_watches'
```

(no matter if I use shell or docker executor).

- Shutdown watchman with command (also in gitlab-ci.yml):

  ```
   watchman watch-del-all && watchman shutdown-server
  ```

... but the error still appears.

- Build docker image with pre-configured value but that's not possible.

**My questions are:**

- Is there any other way to solve this problem without asking admin to change this value on the runner?
- If watchman is needed for 'watch' files when they change then why that's also used for build apk? Maybe is there some way to not using watchman for apk build?

Comment: Hi did you managed to solve this?

Comment: It was necessary to change this value on the gitlab runner machine